# wire library pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, reference

short question. I came upon this line of programming in someone's example code of Teensy Wire

```
 Wire.write((byte *) &data, sizeof data);
```

arguments are (data sending, the size of the data).
I don't understand what the (byte *) &data is for? I'm assuming its taking the address of the data and converting the data to bytes, but I don't know the syntax or why not just put

Wire.write(data, sizeof data);

```
/* Data is a */
struct with{
  int id;
  int data;
}
```

this code is for sending the structure across a wire to another device.

Comment: There is more to it. `Wire.write` is for sending 8 bit data, `int` is probably 16 or 32 bits in arduino. [Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/send-unsigned-long-with-wire-write/587421/3) is a post that will help. What device are you writing to?

Answer (score 1):

`Wire.write` appears to take a pointer to `byte` as its first parameter, so simply passing `data` won't work because `data` is an object not a pointer. `&data` gives a pointer, but not of the expected type. `(byte *)` casts that pointer to one of the proper type.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is valid, I guess the class method `write` is declared like

```
size_t write(const byte* data, size_t size);
```

Thus, it expects a pointer to `byte`. Taking the address `&data` has the type `data*`, the pointer to `with`.

```
Wire.write(&data, sizeof data);
```

would raise the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'write'
    Wire.write(&data, sizeof data);
         ^~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'with *' to 'const byte *' for 1st argument
size_t write(const byte* data, size_t size);
```

because of the different sizes of pointees, `byte` is likely 8-bit type, `wish` with two `int` is more than 32-bit type. The pointer `wish*` should be forcedly type casted to `byte*`, but the safe type cast `static_cast<byte*>(&data)` from `wish*` to `byte *` is not allowed, and the author uses unsafe C-style type cast `(T)v`:

```
Wire.write((byte*)&data, sizeof data);
```